# Cannot implicity Convert Type Threading.Tasks.Task<Collection.Generic.List<Model>> To Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, async-await

I want to get data from .NET API that I include it in reference.
but, badly I got stuck with an exception bellow.

> Error 2   Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<BizCover.Repository.Cars.Car>>` to `BizCover.Api.Cars.Model.CarsVM`

here is my code in API controller.

```
public IHttpActionResult getAllDataCars()
    {
        CarRepository carRep = new CarRepository();

        IHttpActionResult result = null;

        try
        {
            CarsVM dataAPICars = new CarsVM(); 
            dataAPICars = carRep.GetAllCars(); //here's the error return.

            if (dataAPICars != null) 
            {
                var a = "ada";
            }
            else
            {
                var b = "null";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var c = ex.ToString();
        }

        return result;

    }
```

and also here is my model

```
public class CarsVM
{
    public CarsVM()
    {

    }

    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public string CountryManufactured { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public CarsVM(string Colour, string CountryManufactured, int Id, string Make, string Model, decimal Price, int Year)
    {
        this.Colour = Colour;
        this.CountryManufactured = CountryManufactured;
        this.Id = Id;
        this.Make = Make;
        this.Model = Model;
        this.Price = Price;
        this.Year = Year;
    }

}
```

the goals here is I want to get data from reference (CarRepository) and store it in my model.
I did not clearly understand how the .NET Framework API should work step by step and how to implement await async.

Comment: Hi, do you identified the line that produces the error? If so, indicate it in the code please

Answer (score 1):

First, to fix the `Task` issue, you need to await it, so your method signature needs to change to an `async` method:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> getAllDataCars()
```

Don't worry - it will still work as intended. ASP.NET knows what this is.

And then you can `await` the async method that you are calling:

```
dataAPICars = await carRep.GetAllCars();
```

---

Now, this will change your titular problem slightly, but it will still produce essentailly the same problem:

```
Cannot implicity convert type Collection.Generic.List<Model> to Model
```

The problem here is that you have potentially many cars in a list, and you want a single car. Obviously we can't convert a parking garage full of cars into a single car, so C# can't convert a list of cars into a single car.

Assuming there can only ever be one entry, you can use [`SingleOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=netcore-3.1):

```
dataAPICars = (await carRep.GetAllCars()).SingleOrDefault();
```

If there can be multiple, but you only want the first / last, you should use [`.FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netcore-3.1) or [`.LastOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault?view=netcore-3.1):

```
dataAPICars = (await carRep.GetAllCars()).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you do actually want a LIST OF CARS, then you need to change `dataAPICars` into a `List<Model> dataAPICars` instead of a `Model dataAPICars`. Then you can return that list instead of the single item, and of course change checks from `dataAPICars != null` to `dataAPICars.Any()`, etc.

If you want something else, you'll have to figure out how your list of cars becomes a single car, I'm afraid.